# Which Stone Talus gives sapphires?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In the Legend Of Zelda Breath Of The wild, I am looking for sapphires so I can make the sapphire circlet. I am wondering which stone talus (Where) gives sapphires.

Answer (score 6):

The [Rare Stone Talus](https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Stone_Talus_(Rare)) and the [Frost Talus](https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Frost_Talus) have a chance to drop sapphires, but it isn't guaranteed.

The [Igneo Talus](https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Igneo_Talus), [Luminous](https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Stone_Talus_(Luminous)) and regular [Stone Talus](https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/Stone_Talus) do not have any chance to drop Sapphires.